# How add a condition, to detect if there is no overlay?

Tags: overlays

### Situation

I use the package [`vimish-fold`](https://github.com/mrkkrp/vimish-fold/). This package uses overlays, to detect the current state of the fold. I would like to create folds (hence the new function `foobar`), when there is no fold detected.

So I decided to modify the `vimish-fold-toggle` function. The original function:

```
(defun vimish-fold-toggle ()
"Toggle fold at point."
(interactive)
(dolist (overlay (overlays-at (point)))
    (let ((type (overlay-get overlay 'type)))
    (when (eq type 'vimish-fold--folded)
        (vimish-fold-unfold))
    (when (eq type 'vimish-fold--unfolded)
        (vimish-fold-refold)))))
```

To modify it, that will create a fold (calling `foobar) when there is no fold overlay under the point found :

```
(defun vimish-fold-toggle ()
"Toggle fold at point."
(interactive)
(dolist (overlay (overlays-at (point)))
    (let ((type (overlay-get overlay 'type)))
    (when (eq type 'vimish-fold--folded)
        (vimish-fold-unfold))
    (when (eq type 'vimish-fold--unfolded)
        (vimish-fold-refold))


  ;; The added code 
  (if (eq type 'vimish-fold--unfolded)
      (message "nothing")
    (if (eq type 'vimish-fold--folded)
        (message "nothing")
      (foobar)))
  )))
```

The if-statements checks if the type is `vimish-fold--unfolded and`vimish-fold--folded are `nil`, then `foobar` will be called.

### Problem

It seems the function `foobar` is never called, when the point is not positioned on a fold.

It seems there are no overlays at all in my case and thus body of the loop dolist is never executed. I got the suggestion to extract all existing overlays then remove all those that do not satisfy `vimish-fold--vimish-overlay-p`. Result collection will contain all existing folds. Then I could test if it's empty or not. If it's empty, then I could call the function `foobar`.

It seems I have not enough understanding what the overlay actually is, since there is also no overlay on the text fields without fold.I looked [into the documentation of Emacs about overlays](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html), but I couldn't find any relevant section how to detect if there is no overlay under the current pointer.

So if anyone know how I could detect if the point is not located on a fold overlay, then I could call `foobar` instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Try eliminating everything that doesn't directly have to do with whatever the question is, and removing duplication.

Comment: You might be right. I deleted some text and added subparagraphs. I'm looking to understand why `foobar` is never be called, even when there are no overlays under the current location of the pointer.

Comment: @ReneFroger I think it will helps other help you if you are able to replicate your problem using a "minimum working code snippet", independent of an external package like `vimish-fold`. Your current question relies on if `type` is set to `'vimish-fold--unfolded` or `'vimish-fold--folded` correctly. I think you should further break down the `vimish-fold` functions and play with the overlays independently.

Comment: I have not used this library, but it appears to be geared towards initially folding a selected region.  If there is no overlay present and you wish for a toggle to work, are you contemplating that you will have an active region when hitting the toggle?  And if so, `point` could be at the beginning or ending of the selected region -- so the overlay at `point` might be misleading in that regard because one end of the region may have an overlay, whereas the other end of the region may not.  For example, you could mark the region from right to left or visa-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure I understood your question but were you trying to do this?

```el
(defun vimish-fold-toggle ()
  "Toggle fold at point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((there-is-a-fold-at-point nil))
    (dolist (overlay (overlays-at (point)))
      (let ((type (overlay-get overlay 'type)))
        (when (eq type 'vimish-fold--folded)
          (vimish-fold-unfold)
          (setq there-is-a-fold-at-point t))
        (when (eq type 'vimish-fold--unfolded)
          (vimish-fold-refold)
          (setq there-is-a-fold-at-point t))))
    (unless there-is-a-fold-at-point
      (foobar))))
```

Comment: That was correct, thanks for that, I validated your answer as the right one. I never knew you could add `unless` conditional to the `let` prefix. Could you tell me how you figured that out? And unfortunately, I can award my bounty only after 15 hours.

Comment: @ReneFroger You may want to review the ELisp manual: the body of a `let` can hold any forms at all (not sure what you mean by "prefix"). And don't worry about the bounty; maybe you should even wait a few days to see if someone posts a nicer/more comprehensive answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, good tip. I'm reviewing the `let` property now (prefix was the poor word choice here). And I added the bounty to your profile.